# How to use swipe button in tableview for section header and repeated cell in the section in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have a design in which a section header is there and within the section header, its rows are there. I have to provide delete functionality on swipe for the header (Single button) as well as I also have to provide delete buttons for each row in the section. I know to use the swipe button for a single row. But I don't have any idea about my new problem. Anybody has some idea please help me out.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

One idea that comes to mind:
Inside the header view, create a singe-cell table view and put the content in there. This way, you can use the regular Swipe-To-Reveal support of a regular table view cell, even though this all happens inside the header view.

Comment: I am trying with nested tableview